# How to unlex using Flex(The Fast Lexical Analyzer)?

Tags: flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis

Is there any way to put a token back into the input stream using Flex? I imagine some function like `yyunlex()`.

Comment: Is this an Adobe Flex related question or should it be tagged w/ gnu-flex?  The question is so lacking in details, I can't tell.

Comment: Changed the tag from flex to gnu-flex. The former refers to the Adobe Flex framework, and the latter refers to the fast lexical analyzer.

Answer (score 4):

There is the macro `REJECT` which will put the token back to stream and continue to match other the rules as though the first matched didn't. If you just want to put some char back to stream @Kizaru's answer will suffice.

Example snippet:

```
%%
a     |
ab    |
abc   |
abcd  ECHO; REJECT;
.|\n  printf("xx%c", *yytext);
%%
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options.

You can put each character for the token back onto the input stream using `unput(ch)` where ch is the character. This call puts ch as the next character on the input stream (next character to be considered in scanning). So you could do this if you save the string during the token match.

You might want to look into `yyless(0)` which will put all of the characters from the token back onto the input stream too. I never used this one though, so I'm not sure if there are any gotchas. You can specify an integer `n` hwich will put all but the first n characters back on the input stream.

Now, if you're going to do this often during scanning/parsing, you might want to use lex just to build tokens and place the tokens onto your own data structure for parsing. This is akin to what bison and yacc's generated `yyparse()` function does.

Comment: So, if it helps somebody: yyless(0) can put your current token back to the input stream. But calling yyless(0) again is futile - further tokens won't be put back into the input stream.